# How to refresh mapped table in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am rendering a table from mapped elements stored in the React state.  However, the **tr** row elements are not rendered in the **tbody** component, even though console commands show the data is there.  The code to render table rows from `this.state.tableData` is:

```
componentWillMount() {
    let data = this.props.dbPersons.get("directory");
    this.setState({ tableData: data });         
}

...

renderTableData() {
    return this.state.tableData.map((student, index) => {
      const { id, person } = student; 
      console.log("id'", id);
      console.log("person.lastName", person.lastName);

      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td>{person.lastName}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
}
```

**tbody** is rendered if **tableData** is stored in the state:

```
{this.state.tableData && <tbody>
  {this.renderTableData()}
</tbody>}
```

But when the page is opened, the console displays the row data but **tbody** is rendered without any rows.  Why?  Does the component need to be refreshed somehow?  Has the **tbody** component already been rendered and cannot be updated?

Answer (score 0):

Other than componentWillMount causing a warning (replace it with compontDidMount) there is nothing wrong with the code you posted so far. I don't see a reason why it would log but not render. Here is a working example of your code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { tableData: false };
  componentWillMount() {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        this.setState({
          tableData: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
        }),
      500
    );
  }
  renderTableData() {
    return this.state.tableData.map((student, index) => {
      const { id } = student;
      console.log('id', id);
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          {/* <td>{name}</td> removed this but still can see id*/}
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {this.state.tableData && (
          <tbody>{this.renderTableData()}</tbody>
        )}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Maybe you can provide a minim example that demonstrates the behavior you are experiencing.

Answer (score -1):

```
renderTableData() {
  var data = this.state.tableData.map((student, index) => {
    const { id, person } = student; console.log("id'", id);
    console.log("person.lastName", person.lastName);
    return (<tr key={index}>
      <td>{id}</td>
      <td>{person.lastName}</td>
    </tr>)
  })
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Other then messing up code alignment what is it that this is supposed to do?

Comment: Code only answers, without explanation or supporting documentation are frowned upon. SO is a resource for knowledge & learning. Compete, self-contained answers that direct readers to reasoning when/why their solution addresses the OP's issue has more long term value, skews Q & A to highlight knowledge, rather than give-me-code coding service type questions, & helps future visitors apply your answer to their own issues. Finally, well thought out, complete Answers with explanations are much more likely to be upvoted, as they help visitors the most. Please consider editing to add long term value.

Comment: @SherylHohman thanks for the suggestion, I agree with your opinion.